# Cannot Access File hosted in AWS server EC2 type, which is uploaded by a Java code.Any help will be Appreciated

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

> This is my file upload code in java :-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadFileToOnlineStorage",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void uploadFileToOnlineStorage(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam("fileName") String fileName,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        log.info("entered....... Class : UtilityController , Method : uploadFileToOnlineStorage");

        Utils utils = new Utils();
        //String fileName = "";
        this.logEvent(request, "uploadFileToOnlineStorage","");

        String fileStoringLocation = utils.getDataFromApplicationConfig("onlineFileLocation");
        String fileRetrieveUrl = utils.getDataFromApplicationConfig("onlineFileRetrieveUrl");
        final Path filePath = Paths.get(fileStoringLocation);

        String fname = file.getOriginalFilename();
        String fileExtention = fname.split("\\.")[1];

        boolean fileExistCheck = true;
        String storingfilename = "";

        if(fileName.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println("fileName if '' ");
            while(fileExistCheck)
            {
                System.out.println("while ");

                storingfilename = "adw_file_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + fileExtention;

                File uploadedfile = new File(fileStoringLocation + "/" + storingfilename);

                fileExistCheck = uploadedfile.exists();
                System.out.println(fileStoringLocation + "/" + storingfilename);

            }
        }
        else
        {   
            System.out.println("else part ");

            storingfilename = fileName;
            File uploadedfile = new File(fileStoringLocation + "/" + fileName);

            if(uploadedfile.exists() && uploadedfile.isFile())uploadedfile.delete();
        }

        System.out.println("done..");

        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), filePath.resolve(storingfilename));
        System.out.println(fileStoringLocation + "/" + fileName+"..");

        File f = new File(fileStoringLocation + "/" + fileName);

        JsonObject res =  new JsonObject(); 
        res.addProperty("filePath",  fileRetrieveUrl + "/" + storingfilename);
        String message =  utils.getEventMessage("fileUploadSuccess");
        log.info("exit....... Class : UtilityController , Method : uploadFileToOnlineStorage");

        ResponseSender.sendSuccessResponse(response,res,message);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error(e.getMessage());

        JsonObject res =  new JsonObject();
        String message =  new Utils().getEventMessage("unknownError");
        ResponseSender.sendErrorResponse(response,res,message);
    }

}
```

> When i am uploading a file (with my UI) to AWS server ec2 type where it is currently hosted
>   and after that ,trying accessing it
>   with url "http://18.222.150.94:9000/adwOnlineFileStorage/adw_file_1550303331687.html"

Responding me with this message[image]

> If I try giving file permission by terminal manually through ssh client connection to server by following permission code in the folder

"chmod 777 -R adw_file_1550303674861.html"

After that by same url hitting like above its giving me access to file.

> How can i solve this problem by code or 
>   something need to be done with AWS (As I am new to AWS )
>   as I cannot always manually give file permission and give access to file.

Comment: Api to upload and view the file on portal, is it the same application?

Comment: No, uploading it by a api and then viewing it in firefox  with url "http://18.222.150.94:9000/adwOnlineFileStorage/adw_file_1550303331687.html" (a location where file exist ) .

Comment: so possibly the username who is uploading the file is different than the who is retrieving the file. One possible solution is to setup a cron job that gives permissions to all files under the required directory every few seconds.

Comment: Thanks,but will it be optimise solution as it will run every few seconds and can you please elaborate this how will i implement as it is hosted to aws, so i need to give file permission for there,right?